# How to set custom claims with FirebaseUser?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add some key-value pairs to custom claims but can't find any function for this. How do you do it on Android?

For example, I am able to set the Display Photo this way:

```
FirebaseUser user = ...;
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                            .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(response.body().getPhotoURI()))
                            .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(task -> { ... });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Client SDK its a risk as malicious clients can also modify the data**. May be claims can be added in console now which i am not certain. And that might be something that's what your looking for. From [Controlling Data Access Using Firebase Auth Custom Claims](https://medium.com/google-developers/controlling-data-access-using-firebase-auth-custom-claims-88b3c2c9352a):

> It might sound like a good idea to add all sorts of criteria as custom claims. Perhaps you want to add a home address, additional photo URLs, or a profile description, for example. But this is not what custom claims are designed for. Data like addresses should be stored in a database, since it’s not related to authentication. Tokens are not profiles!

And from [Set and validate custom user claims via the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk):

> Custom claims can contain sensitive data, therefore they should only be set from a privileged server environment by the Firebase Admin SDK.

> ```
> // Set admin privilege on the user corresponding to uid.
> Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
> claims.put("admin", true);
> FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setCustomUserClaims(uid, claims);
> ```

> The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
> next time a new one is issued.

> And Using It:

> ```
> // Verify the ID token first.
> FirebaseToken decoded = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken);
> if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(decoded.getClaims().get("admin"))) {
>   // Allow access to requested admin resource.
> }
> ```

OR As Client:

> ```
> // Lookup the user associated with the specified uid.
> UserRecord user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(uid);
> boolean claim = Boolean.parseBoolean(user.getCustomClaims().get("admin"));
> ```

You might want to read this: [Firebase Custom Claim Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#java)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set custom claims directly in the client app.  That would be considered a security problem. Custom claims is a flexible security mechanism that allows you to grant the user access to backend resources.  If users could grant themselves custom claims, then they would be an ineffective method of securing resources.

You should use the Firebase Admin SDK to assign custom claims on a backend you control, and make sure that the claims only are granted for users in the specific situations that you allow - users should not be able to assign themselves custom claims.

Comment: Actually, I want to use custom claims key-value pairs to avoid having to deal with Firebase DB as I have to save some key-value pair to `FirebaseUser`. It's just convenient for my use case - Firebase Authentication is perfect for me, but I need to store just one more variable per each user.

Comment: I understand your use case, but it's not possible.